# Wearing a tooth guard

Tags: acid-base

Since I have been advised by my Dentist to wear a 'Tooth Guard' at night because apparently I grind my teeth, my top front teeth under the guard are disappearing, some now only about 3mms from the gum. Are they being dissolved by acid in my saliva?
Regards,
David Bowley (Scotland)

Comment: Hi David, please do ask your dentist what is happening - if you trust random Internet people more than you trust your dentist, perhaps it's time to find a new one ;)